# Send out-of-office reply for every SMTP record

Tags: exchange-2016, outlook-2013

When someone leaves the company their mailbox is deleted and the SMTP record is added to a `noreply@company.com` mailbox.

On the mailbox we added an out-of-office notifying the sender that person they are trying to reach is no longer with the company. After a couple of months the record is removed from the mailbox.

(thank God this is all automated...)

However, if *Alice* is sending an email to *Bob* who has left the company, she will receive an OoO from the mailbox. If after an hour she sends an email to *Carl* who left the company too, she no longer will receive the OoO because the is hitting the same mailbox.

Is there a way to get around this issue? Or is there a better way to handle disabled mailboxes?

Comment: Just delete the mailbox. The bounce message is notification enough that the person is no longer there.

Comment: Management finds this rather unprofessional. Also some less 'savvy' employees might start calling IT because "they can send mail to xxx".

Comment: You can refer to this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/157961/only-one-reply-is-sent-to-each-sender-when-the-out-of-office-assistant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An out-of-office message on an Exchange mailbox is only replied to once during the lifetime of that specific out-of-office message.

To reply to every incoming mail you should delete the out-of-office message but instead add the reply via a rule.